# Flex push one item below the others that are next to each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Flex is sometimes killing me, here's a simple code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">1</div><div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
```

I want to end up with something of this sort:

```
[   .one  ][.two]

[    .three.    ]
```

It's super easy using block/inline-block:

```
.one { display: inline-block; width: 80%; }
.two { display: inline-block; width: 20%; }
.three { display: block; width: 100%; } /* Don't even need the with here, added for clarity */
```

But of course nothing is easy with flexbox ;) I don't want (and can't) change flex-direction, it has to stay as the default value (I think that's not an issue, because `.one` and `.two` are actually next to each other). Unfortunately because of that I have no clue how to push `.three` below them, the sane way would be something like this:

```
.wrapper { display: flex; }
.one { width: 80%; }
.two { width: 20%; }
.three { width: 100%; } /* move to the next line as you cant fit in the current! */
```

But all I'm getting is:

```
[.one][.two][   .three  ]
```

I've tried `align-self` and everything I could find but nothing seem to help.

To sum up:

1. I can't affect the DOM structure or the parents css.
2. I don't want to add any `.break` or `.clear` empty elements or pseudoelements because its not 1997 anymore and makes everything even more complex (somehow the first example does not need all that sorcery).
3. I'd rather not add next layer of abstraction (I think I could wrap one/two in a div and then three in another, but boy, why all that hustle for something that simple?).

How can I achieve simple two column / two row layout with flexbox? Am I missing something? I feel like something is wrong here. Thank you.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rh9vpb2e/

Comment: just add `flex-flow: wrap;` to `.wrapper`

Answer (score 1):

So close!

You just need;

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

on the `.wrapper` class to ensure flex wraps the rows!

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qz5er27s/1/)

[`flex-wrap` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

Comment: I cant add any classes of the parent element, but it makes total sense now, i'm a moron I guess. I will just add it using JS and to hell with it, thank you. I think `flex-wrap: wrap;` should be the default value!